# Что не так в запросе?

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Есть две таблицы datacenter, photo в datacenter хранится name, surname, а в photo хранится name_avatar, has_avatar

Проблема в том, что

```
 echo $row['name_avatar'];
 echo $row['has_avatar'];
```

Не чего не выводит

```
  $a = mysql_query("
  SELECT datacenter.name, datacenter.surname, senderInfo.name_avatar, senderInfo.has_avatar                  
 FROM datacenter 
 LEFT JOIN photo AS senderInfo 
 ON datacenter.name = senderInfo.name_avatar
 WHERE datacenter.id_school = '$id_school'") 
 or die(mysql_error());

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($a))
 {
 echo $row['name'];
 echo $row['surname'];
 echo $row['name_avatar'];
 echo $row['has_avatar'];
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Навскидку - запрос абсолютно корректный, могу предположить что ничего не выводится потому, что

```
datacenter.name
```

не равняется

```
senderInfo.name_avatar
```